# What's the correct/best way to auto generate tables in the database?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**UPDATE 1:**
I do have a fully functional DbContext class / model classes

Also: Seems like I don't need services.AddDbContext when I override OnConfiguring in my DbContext

My DbContext derived class:

```
namespace PersonHobbies.Models 
{
    public class DataBaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataBaseContext() {}
        public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<DataBaseContext> options) 
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public virtual DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Hobby> Hobby { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;User Id=SA;password=<mypassword>;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=False");
            }
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // nothing?
        }

    }
```

My "Person" model class:

```
namespace PersonHobbies.Models {
    public class Person {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My "Hobby" model class:

```
namespace PersonHobbies.Models {
    public class Hobby {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]            
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

In an example I found, it was done l in the Startup class like this:

```
namespace PersonHobbies
{
    public class Startup
    {                        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataBaseContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            }
         }   
     }

}
```

However, when I try to run the program, I get an exception.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll but was not
>   handled in user code: 'No service for type
>   'PersonHobbies.Models.DataBaseContext' has been registered.'

I'm new to all this, but it sounds like this is the wrong place to do this. When is my DbContext based class (DataBaseContext) registered?

**UPDATE 2:**

When using OnConfiguring, it looks like it should be done like this:

```
using (var context = new DataBaseContext())
{
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

I get no exception, but the tables are not created

Comment: Is that all of your code? There is not enough there to even start an answer. I suggest you look at [this EFCore tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2), specifically the section on [registering the context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2#register-the-schoolcontext)

Comment: Added more code as requested.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` line in your `UPDATE 2` does it ever get hit? I doubt it. You will need to register the context if you want to use it anywhere else in your code. The link I gave above has a section on [Initialize the DB with test data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2#initialize-db-with-test-data). That shows you how to ensure the DB is created when your app starts (as well as adding some test data to the tables - but you can ignore that bit if you want to).